# Apache Tomcat for 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, tomcat

I have a web application running in Windows XP Professional SP2. I am trying to port the application to Windows 7 64-Bit. I was using Apache Tomcat 5.5. Can the same be used for Windows 7 64-Bit or is there a different version for 64-bit architecture? I could not find any such downloads in the site.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is written in Java. Java is (at least in theory) platform independent. Just install a 64-bit JVM on your system and run Tomcat on it.